# How to get the Commits against a VSTS WorkItem that uses Git as source control

Tags: azure-devops-rest-api

I have a VSTS project that uses Git for source control. The project has multiple repositories (11 to be precise) each with multiple branches.

Given a VSTS Id I am trying to get a list of all the Commits that are associated with that Id.

I am currently coding as follows

```
        VSTSHelper helper = new VSTSHelper(); // my helper for establishing a connection

        ProjectHttpClient projectClient = helper.Connection.GetClient&lt;ProjectHttpClient&gt;();
        GitHttpClient gitClient = helper.Connection.GetClient&lt;GitHttpClient&gt;();
        Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Core.WebApi.TeamProject project = projectClient.GetProject(helper.Project).Result;
        List&lt;GitRepository&gt; gitRepositoryList = gitClient.GetRepositoriesAsync(project.Id).Result;

        GitQueryCommitsCriteria criteria = new GitQueryCommitsCriteria()
        {
            IncludeWorkItems = true
        };

        foreach (GitRepository repo in gitRepositoryList)
        {
            List&lt;GitBranchStats&gt; branchStatsList = gitClient.GetBranchesAsync(repo.Id).Result;

            foreach (GitBranchStats branchStats in branchStatsList)
            {
                criteria.ItemVersion = new GitVersionDescriptor() { Version = branchStats.Name, VersionType = GitVersionType.Branch };

                List&lt;GitCommitRef&gt; commits = gitClient.GetCommitsAsync(repo.Id, criteria).Result;

                if (commits.Count &gt; 0)
                {
                    List&lt;GitCommitRef&gt; commitsWithWorkItems = commits.Where(pc =&gt; pc.WorkItems.Count &gt; 0).ToList();

                    if (commitsWithWorkItems.Count &gt; 0)
                    {   
                        // WorkItemIds is a list of int
                        List&lt;GitCommitRef&gt; workItemCommits = projectCommitsWithWorkItems.Where(
                            pc =&gt; pc.WorkItems.Any(x =&gt; this.WorkItemIds.Contains(Convert.ToInt32(x.Id)))).ToList();

                        // get the changes associated with the commit here
                        if (workItemCommits.Count &gt; 0)
                        {
                            foreach (GitCommitRef wiCommit in workItemCommits)
                            {
                                GitCommitChanges wiChanges = gitClient.GetChangesAsync(wiCommit.CommitId, repo.Id).Result;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

The work item id that is passed to my code (e.g Id = 810) has code that was originally committed against another Work Item Id (e.g. 675) in a different branch and then moved to the given Id. The code was then edited and then committed against the new Id (810)

My code above only ever finds the original commit against item 675 - and all the code changes are shown against this Id - including those that I was expecting to see against 810. Nothing is ever returned for Id 810.

Despite lots of googling I find myself struggling big time and I presume that I am misunderstanding some big time!

Any help or pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below code to get all the commits which link to a given work item:

As the REST API [GET a work item with Fully expanded](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/work-items#fully-expanded), all the links information exist under `relations` object. Then you can get the commits by filtering the url which contains `vstfs:///Git/Commit`.

```
int id = workitemID;
var token = "PAT";
String Uri = "https://account.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection";
var Connection1 = new VssConnection(new Uri(Uri), new VssBasicCredential(string.Empty, token));
WorkItemTrackingHttpClient workItemTrackingClient = Connection1.GetClient<WorkItemTrackingHttpClient>();
WorkItem workitem = workItemTrackingClient.GetWorkItemAsync(id, expand: WorkItemExpand.All).Result;
Console.WriteLine("Related commits contain: ");
    foreach (var relation in workitem.Relations)
    {
       if (relation.Url.Contains("vstfs:///Git/Commit"))
        {
           Console.WriteLine("commit:  {0}", relation.Url);
        }
    }
```

To Get the commit sha-1 value (commit ID), it's located in the last 40 characters of the `relation.Url` which separate with repository ID by `%2f`. So the url format actually is `vstfs:///Git/Commit/{projectID}%2f{repositoryID}%2f{commitID}`.

Such as for a `relation.Url` as below:

```
vstfs:///Git/Commit/f7855e29-6f8d-429d-8c9b-41fd4d7e70a4%2fad3acf8e-b269-48e5-81bc-354251856b51%2fb802c91e68f321676fe31eca9dda048e7032ea11"
```

- The commit sha-1 value is `b802c91e68f321676fe31eca9dda048e7032ea11`.
- The repository ID is `ad3acf8e-b269-48e5-81bc-354251856b51`.
- The project ID is `f7855e29-6f8d-429d-8c9b-41fd4d7e70a4`.

Comment: HI,Thanks for the reply. This is the approach I had taken initially but unfortunately I do not seem to get the Commit reference - all the work item has is a Git/Ref entry. My somewhat inefficient code above was an attempt to understand what was going on.
I can only conclude that although I am assured that code is being committed against the item concerned it is not!

Once again thank you for your assistance

Comment: You can get the commit information from the url. And I added the detail analysis for the url in the last part of my answer. You can have a try.